# SQL Server CE - Merge replication - 0x80004005 / 0x80040e37

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, compact-framework

I have a legacy .NET Compact Framework 2.0 solution running on some Windows CE 5 devices. The solution has been running since 2009 and have been updated several times because the SQL Server was upgraded or moved to new server.

The solution collects data into a local SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2 database, with 8 tables. 5 of the tables are subscriber download-only containing meta / system data. The last 3 tables are bidirectional and used to upload the collected data from the device. The SQL Server is a 2008 (10.0.5520) and we are using a Windows Server with SQL Server CE Server Tools / Web Synchronization installed (IIS from now on) to make the merge replication possible from the devices and into the SQL Server. The SQL Server and the IIS is hosted on different servers.

About 1-2 months back we were starting to have some problems completing the synchronization from the devices. I exported one of the local database from a device and used SSMS to connect to the file. I forced a synchronization for each subscription and everything worked fine. I re-installed all my devices with the software and a clean local database, did a full synchronization for all the subscriptions on the devices and everything completed with success.

2 weeks ago we saw some strange behaviour when trying to synchronize the subscriptions on the devices. The 3 tables that are bidirectional failed while trying to synchronize and threw some errors. I dropped all subscriptions on all devices and deleted all publications on the SQL Server. I recreated all publications on the SQL Server and did subscribe to each by hand in a new local database file using SSMS. Everything worked fine and I re-installed 2 devices from scratch with a new local database file and

Then today I wanted to install a third device to make sure the system was still working and to start getting the devices back to the users. I couldn't complete the synchronization on the device and received an error. I quickly turned to my two devices that I got working the last time - they synchronize with no problem. Confused by my findings I started SSMS and tried to use an empty local database file, so I could make sure that the publications were working. Once again the bidirectional tables / publications failed when trying to subscribe to them.

I developed a custom tool (winforms) in .NET 4.0, using a reference for the SQL CE 3.5 SP2 dll file and tried to synchronize a new local database file. Again I received an error.

I can't seem to find anything useful in the Event log / Error log in SQL on the server hosting the SQL Server instance. I found one error in the event log but it is only presence once:

```
Date        30-06-2015 10:40:06
Log     Windows NT (Application)

Source      MSSQLSERVER
Category        Server
Event       3221239623
Computer        XZY

Message
Replication-Replication Merge Subsystem: agent 0037007B-0039-0035-4400-370041003400 failed. The SQL statement failed to execute. If this occurred while using merge replication, this is an internal error. If this occurred while using RDA, then the SQL statement is invalid either on the PULL statement or on the SubmitSQL statement. [,,,SQL stateme
```

On the IIS server we found the following error message: 
**"2015/06/30 15:35:34 Hr=80004005 ACK:Error for DistributorSessionID =  1752"**

The error was taken from **"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\sync\SQL\XYZ"** path.

When using the custom tool the exception only contains the following string: **"The specified table does not exist."**
The error from the custom tool is somewhat connected to the error from the IIS, because the errors from the IIS keeps growing for each time I do synchronization.

Looking at the publications from the replication monitor tool included in SSMS I can see that a synchronization was performed / started for each publication, even the bidirectional ones that fails all the time.

See the properties of the article from one of the tables that is subscriber download only and works every time we do a synchronization.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt1G7.jpg

See the properties of the article from one of the tables that is bidirectional and fails every time 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxlyh.jpg

Can any of you give me any direction on how to troubleshoot this issue? We could delete all subscriptions, recreate all publications and complete a reinstall of all our devices. But I need to know what I'm fighting against so we don't see the error later during the summer.

SQL Server:

- Windows Server 2008 SP2 Standard edition
- SQL Server 2008 Standard edition

IIS Server:

- Windows Server 2012 Standard edition
- SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2 + CU 6 / CU 7

Comment: I would try the sync via the Merge Replication test form in my SQL Compact Toolbox add-in, it will capture and display any client side errors properly - and do you see any errors in Replication monitor?

Comment: The Replication monitor tool doesn't show any errors from the synchronizations I'm trying to activate now. I got some old errors on two of my publications but they don't relate to the device I'm working on with these tests.

Comment: OK; what are the client error messages?

Comment: I'm having problems getting Visual Studio installed on the clients servers. They need to free up some diskspace or assign more storage and we are waiting for that to happen. Their servers are hosted and things aren't moving that fast.

Comment: You can just use the standalone SQL CE Toolbox, no need to install full VS

Comment: Oh - I missed that option! I will look into the matter over the next few days! I will post when I have some more information :)

Comment: @ErikEJ I finally downloaded the standalone edition of your toolbox. I opened a Compact database (fresh) and tried to add a new subscription but received an error. See: http://cubeupload.com/im/boAp4j.png.

I took one of my test compact databases with some subscriptions and was able to do a synchronization without any problems. Unfortunately the subscriptions that I'm struggling with cannot be added because of the above error.

Comment: You also need to share the parameters used in the Sync form, thanks!